# Precedence or powers - Is there more than one way

Tags: power-towers

I'm developing a calculator and I've encountered this issue:

2<sup>2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup></sup> which power should be calculated first, is there a way this could be solved from the left to the right, meaning 4<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup> and so on.... I believe that it's wrong, and you should start from the right most power and go down. But I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard notation is that if you write it without parentheses then it is evaluated from right to left and you have to use explicit parentheses for a left to right evaluation:

$3^{3^3}=3^{27}$ but $(3^3)^3=27^3$